# Cycle through List and Ordering

Tags: c, arraylist, linked-list, structure

I want to create a linked list.
The user adds numbers and the idea is that the numbers are inserted to the list in descending order.

Here goes what I did, but when rearranging, it just orders the first number...

```
int addInputNumber(numberList **node){

  numberList *temp;
  int userInput;
  temp = (numberList*)malloc(sizeof(numberList));
  //Memory Check
  if ( temp == 0 )//out of memory, return 0
      return 0;
  //Get the users input
  printf("Give me a Number!\n");
  scanf("%d",&userInput);

 //Add it to the list.
  temp->numbero = userInput;
  ///Link to the list.
  temp->next = *node; 
  *node = temp; 

  //Lets cycle through the list.
  numberList *temp2;
  int helpNumber;
  temp2 = *node;

  //Rearrange the list.
  while(temp2 != 0){
    if(temp->numbero < temp2->numbero){

      //Switch position..
      helpNumber= temp2->numbero;
      temp2->numbero = temp->numbero;
      temp->numbero = helpNumber;
      temp2 = *node;// If we change number, we must cycle from the beginning AGAIN. 
    }//eof if
    temp2 = temp2->next;
  }//eof while

  return 0;
}//eof addNUmber function.
```

Here's the structure just in case:

```
typedef struct dynamicNumberList {
  int numbero;
  struct dynamicNumberList *next;
}numberList;
```

I've got 2 quick questions.

1. Why would it only arrange the first number?
2. This list adds a space towards the left (visually), how could I make it so I can add a space to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get into the habit of creating one function per task, instead of cramming everything into a single one. It makes the code easier to read and reuse and reduces the chance of errors.

A correct implementation could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s_List
{
  int n;
  struct s_List *next;
} List;

void print_list (List *head)
{
    List *ptr;

    for (ptr = head; ptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
        printf ("%d\t", ptr->n);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}

List * make_node (int n, List *next)
{
    List * node = malloc (sizeof(List));
    node->n = n;
    node->next = next;
    return node;
}

void insert_number_front (List **head, int n)
{
    *head = make_node (n, *head);
}

void insert_number_after (List *prev, int n)
{
    prev->next = make_node (n, prev->next);
}

// If HEAD is sorted, it will stay sorted after insertion
void insert_number_sorted (List **head, int n)
{
    List *ptr;
    List *ptr2;

    // search for the rightmost node whose number is smaller than n.
    ptr2 = NULL;
    for (ptr = *head; ptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
        if (ptr->n >= n)
            break;
        ptr2 = ptr;
    }

    // If such a node exists we insert the new node after it,
    // otherwise we insert it at the front of the list.
    if (ptr2) {
        insert_number_after (ptr2, n);
    }
    else {
        insert_number_front (head, n);
    }
}   

int input_number ()
{
    int n;

    printf ("enter a number: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    return n;
}

int main ()
{
    List *head = NULL;
    int i;

    // By adding elements exclusively with insert_number_sorted()
    // we ensure the list is always sorted
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int n;

        n = input_number ();
        insert_number_sorted (&head, n);
    }

    print_list (head);

    return 0;
}
```

To answer your second question, what you have here is a singly linked list, which can be described by a pointer to the first node. If you want to be able to insert nodes at the back you need to maintain an additional pointer to the last node. However this is not necessary in this case.

Comment: The opening paragraph is very accurate!

Comment: @Antoine Mathys
Thank you for your help!
I've got a question though, I understood almost everything except insert_node_sorted. Im not really understanding what the for(ptr=... and the if(ptr2) are for.
If you could explain I would be very grateful!
And I will make functions for every specific part as a habit. Thank you for your advice and help!

Comment: @AntoineMathys Thank you very much. I just saw your edit, It helped but I couldn't make what this says, im not that advanced haha:  tmp = ptr2 ? &(ptr2->next) : head;....which Im guessing does the same that the if(ptr2) did.....

Comment: @AntoineMathys you pretty much gave me the code there, I really do thank you, but I see this"ptr2 ? &(ptr2->next) : head;" How could I look this up to find more information? Im not getting what '?', '&(ptr2->next)' and ': head;' means. Im assuming that &ptr2->next is being given the reference of head. But I would like to know as what do ? and : mean. Sorry, Im learning through internet haha

Comment: @AntoineMathys
Amazing, thank you very much. I was not aware of this operators. 

Could I add a previous link inside this list creation?? If so, where would I modify this code?(Im assuming I would just need to add when creating the node just node-prev = NULL; and when linking node->prev = ptr2; right??